# Angular FormBuilder not applying element values when HTML added through javascript

Tags: html, angular, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I am trying to semi-dynamically build a form on angular. I have this function which creates the form in component.ts and adds the form HTML. Now the problem is, when I use it, it does not apply the values to the form elements. It does work on the other hand if the HTML is hard coded and the `FormGroup` is created at `ngOnInit();`

```
 private createForm(): void {
    this.displayForm2 = new FormGroup({
      profileName: new FormControl('test')
    });

    document.getElementById('form-div').innerHTML = 
       `<form [formGroup]="displayForm2">
             <label for="profileName">Name: </label>
             <input type="text" formControlName="profileName"><br>
        </form>`;
}
```

I think the problem is because the HTML is added through the function rather than hard coded but I am not 100% sure and don't know how to fix it, any ideas?

Comment: it's impossible, re-thinking the problem and try use Angular to create the form. You can try create a file.json and create the form using the json or some similar

Comment: makes sense although I think I got the solution at least for now, I posted the summary below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to overcome this problem by:

1. Hard coding the form in html file.
2. Creating the `FormGroup` with its `FormControls` in `ngOnInit()`.
3. Made a function to edit the values of the `FormGroup` using `patchValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Pipe :

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'safeHtml'
})
export class SafeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(value: any, ...args: any[]): any {
     return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value);
  }

}
```

And in html you can do :

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHtmlString | safeHtml"></div>
```

See https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/SafeHtml

Comment: Due to my low level of knowledge about Angular I completely don't understand how this relates to my problem but thanks anyway. I have managed to overcome my problem and I will post my solution below.